Nuxt3 append component with reactive props
I'm trying to append a component to the Dom element, I want to the props be reactive (when the value of labelModel changes, the value of the component label changes too).
I tried these three ways, the component added but the props aren't reactive.
// 1
const vueComponent = h(ShortAnswer, {
  'label': labelModel
});

render(vueComponent, document.getElementById('t'))


// 2
let vnode = createVNode(ShortAnswer, {
  'label': labelModel
})
render(vnode, document.getElementById('t'))


// 3
let app = createApp(ShortAnswer, {
  'label': labelModel
})
app.mount('#t')`


You create new app instance any way. You shouldn't do this if you expect ShortAnswer to be aware of your main app. Use a teleport instead if you're able to
